# How do I dynamically resize font within bootstrap modals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, autoresize

stackoverflow.com has saved me many times, but this is actually the first time I've posted a question. Thanks in advance for your help you smart people!

I'm trying to use jquery-quickfit (https://github.com/chunksnbits/jquery-quickfit/blob/master/demo/index.html) to automatically resize a chunk of text that appears within modals. I'm using boostrap to handle the modals (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).

Right now, the text will only resize properly after I open a modal after I resize the window. When it loads, the text appears smaller (I'm not sure where it's inheriting that initial size). I'd like the javascript to kick in the moment the modal is triggered. I'm sure there's an obvious way to do this, but I'm not all that javascript savvy.

This is how the relevant code looks:

```
<button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my-modal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="my-modal" class="modal hide fade row">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="span3 modalicon">
      <i class="icon-image"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="span9" id="modaltextcontainer">
      <span class="modaltext">This is the content I want resized</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.quickfit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      $('.modaltext').quickfit({ max: 40, min: 0, truncate: false });     

    });
    $(window).trigger('resize');    
  });
</script>

<span id="meassure" style="position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px; font-size: 12px;">..........</span>
```

I assume I need to incorporate the bootstrap modal show event in that last bit of javascript, I just can't figure out how.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could bind quickfit after you show modal like this:

```
$('#my-modal').on('show', function() {
   $('.modaltext').quickfit({ max: 40, min: 0, truncate: false });
});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. That didn't quite work. I think the way the quickfit script calculates the new font size is based on the width of the container (though I could be wrong about that). On "show" it looks like the css transition hasn't finished, so it's not calculating the font size correctly? I tried "shown" instead, and that seems to work okay. Two issues, though. Theres a delay between the modal showing and the font is correctly resized. Also, it no longer resizes when the window is resized. (By the way, is there a way to do line breaks in these comments?)

Comment: You could try with `word-break: break-all;` property of the text container. It will automatically break your text to fit container.

Comment: That doesn't hit what I'm going for. For more context, the text that will be resized will be something like a phone number, email address, or url and they'll be a variety of lengths (some people will have a short email address, others will have a long one). I'd like that text to stay on one line and grow or shrink to fit the container. That way, that text will show clearly no matter the window size or the length of the user data. Thanks for your help with this.